# How to use Dozer with Spring Boot and exclude some properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, dozer

I use Dozer in my springboot app, so I put in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.dozermapper</groupId>
    <artifactId>dozer-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>6.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And now I wanna to exclude some field from 2 entitys (id fields), there are some annotations do use? or via xml (a sample please)

tks

Answer (score 0):

> Use the above annotation on the fields which you want to be excluded.
>
> Inside the dozer-config.xml file do wildcard=false

```
<mapping **wildcard="false"**>
    <class-a><package_name><class_name></class-a>
    <class-b><package_name><class_name></class-b>
</mapping>

@Mapping("this")
```